# Using Eval to check for a particular Date Value

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to set a label in a gridview not to show a particular date if it is returned (it is because it is a default date and is not needed).

The code I have used is

```
<%# 'Convert.ToString(Eval("DateTaken")).Equals("01/01/1899") ? "" : Eval("DateTaken")'%>
```

Unfortunately, when I try and compile it the code won't run. I have tried to find an answer by research, but have not been able to do so.

Comment: What is the error that it gives you? I assume when you say it won't run you are getting some kind of error warning that might point to the exact problem you are having...

Comment: Also I've just noticed that the content of your block is wrapped in single quotes (`'`). Is this correct (ie is that what the original code has)? I'm not sure at a glance that they should be there.

Comment: It is on the compiling. it is saying missing ; and missing :. This is on the markup

Comment: Yes, if I remove the logic and just have it as <% #Eval("DateTaken") '%> It all works, and the default date comes through. What I am trying to do is say if the date is equal to this default date then text value is to be blank

Comment: I get what you are wanting to do. I think you were misunderstanding me. Hopefully what I've put in an answer will make it more clear what I was suggesting.

Comment: Hi Chris. Funny I managed just to do that, but when I tested it it was still showing the date and not showing empty text field

Answer (score 0):

```
<%# 'Convert.ToString(Eval("DateTaken")).Equals("01/01/1899") ? "" : Eval("DateTaken")'%>
```

This is not valid syntax as far as I am aware. You have single quotes `'` wrapping your statement which is likely confusing the parser a lot. I'm not sure what you intend them to be doing but I'd suggest trying without:

```
<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("DateTaken")).Equals("01/01/1899") ? "" : Eval("DateTaken")%>
```

I can't test this but it looks like it should work.

Also for the comparison (I assumed you'd tested that elsewhere first) I suspect you may have problems with the fact that `Convert.ToString` likely includes a time element. Instead I would suggest specifying what string format you want to be outputted. Or even better assuming that it is a DateTime you are getting back compare it as a DateTime. Either of the following should work as a reliable comparison

```
(((DateTime)Eval("DateTaken")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")=="2014-03-05")
(((DateTime)Eval("DateTaken")).Date==new DateTime(2014,03,05))
```

Answer (score 0):

It uses part of Chris's answer, but Equals does not work. Changing this to Contains does when parsing the value as year

Comment: I've added a new part to my answer talking about the comparison. I hadn't really looked at your logic, just at the first problem you were getting. Also this shouldn't really have been added as an answer since it doesn't actually answer your question itself. Perhaps you meant to comment on my answer?